# VIM: Perform two actions at once

Tags: vim

I often save `:w` and commit to SVN `svn commit -m "Ticket 351"` as two operations. Is there a way to combine them into a single operation so that I might just <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>⇑</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> when the need arises? I don't want to map a key as I will sometimes have to change the commit message.

Thanks.

Comment: Remember, `@:` to repeat the last command is probably quicker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `|` as a command separator (see `:help :bar`):

```
:w|!svn commit -m foo
```

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly the separator that I needed. So naive that I didn't know the term. Thanks!

Comment: @caligula: Yes, I couldn't mark the answer as accepted for a few minutes. I've done it now!

Answer (score 2):

You could also write a function. E.g. something like;

```
function! Commit(msg)

    write

    let response = system('svn commit -m "' . a:msg . '"')

    echo response

endfunction
```

Then later:

```
:call Commit('ticket 1234')
```

Comment: Thank you, I will consider that.

Answer (score 1):

@JoshLee gives the literal answer. However, why is a keybinding unacceptable to you?

```
nnoremap <Leader>s :w<bar>!svn commit -m<space>
```

will still let you write your commit message before you push Enter...